# Can I share buckets in Amazon S3 so that multiple users see them in their management console?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Using account A, I can add user B to the permissions of a bucket, but that bucket does not then show up in user B's management console.

1. What does it mean to give a user permissions in this way?
2. Is it possible for 2 users to truly have the same access to a bucket, so that it shows up in both consoles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Buckets are fully private by default so basically you allow their AWS account the [selected] permissions to your bucket.
2. Nope. But I think this feature is coming soon. If you notice the bucket properties it has a line for who the owner is :)

Other tools have what's called an "External Bucket" feature to add other user's buckets they have permission for.

If the S3 console is important enough, see if the newly released "AWS Identity and Access Management" feature can get the job done:

http://aws.amazon.com/iam/